# Set marker color when using google-maps-for-rails gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

How do pass color parameter to google maps api using google-maps-for-rails?  I would like to set color of each marker inside controller based on a value, so some would be red, some yellow and some green.  I believe it is the icon property, in Symbol, looking at:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions

Also, I would like to have a number from 1-99 inside the marker, is it possible? So far I have this.

```
@json = Device.all.to_gmaps4rails do |device, marker|
end
```

I have been struggling with this for days, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should simply leverage the google's chart api.

Example, the following is a marker with:

- letter A
- red color: `FF0000`
- black text: `000000`

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|FF0000|000000

So you should customize your needs:

```
@json = Device.all.to_gmaps4rails do |device, marker|
   marker.picture({
     :picture => "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|FF0000|000000", # up to you to pass the proper parameters in the url, I guess with a method from device
     :width   => 32,
     :height  => 32
   })
end
```

Comment: this could be interesting in the gem's wiki

Comment: Thank you, that did work in model, but when I try in controller, it does not seem to change the marker.

Comment: I see no reason why and the code is speced... I'll look again later

Comment: how did you do in controller?

Comment: As you have shown to me above.  I must be missing something little.  I even tried _marker.title "I am the marker"_ and it does not seem to work.  But it did work before.

Comment: so weird, which version do you use?

Comment: Wow, I had a stupid attack, what you wrote is perfect, it works, I am even embarrassed to describe my mistake. SOLVED! and THANK-YOU

Comment: Can i replace "A" with "You are Here!"

Comment: DEPRECATION WARNING: These dynamic icons are great but they are part of the deprecated "Image Charts".  If you have found a similar alternative please post back.

Comment: To get this to work, I had to use ``:url`` in stead of ``:picture``.

Comment: @Troy set the api has slighty changed and is documented

Answer (score 4):

I implemented the above solution to no avail, but now figured out why this wasn't working. Perhaps this was an update to the gem, but "url" is the right key for the URL of the picture, not "picture". Here was my code in my controller:

```
@devices_hash= Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@devices) do |device, marker|
  ...
  marker.picture({
     :url => "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|007FFF|000000",
     :width   => 32,
     :height  => 32
  })
end
```

Hope this helps some people struggling with the same thing.